# Multiple AlertView with tags, can't cancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I searched Stack for ways to implement multiple `alertViews`. Most of the answers were to use Tags. This way works great, except for one huge thing- the cancel button! When the `alertView` pops up, whether you tap "**cancel**" or "**yourButtonTitle**", your action goes through. Is there a way to cancel an `alertView` with Tags?

Here is my code:

```
#define TAG_ONE 1
#define TAG_TWO 2

- (IBAction)someButton1 {

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call" message:@"Call number?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];

alertView.tag = TAG_ONE;
[alertView show];
}

- (IBAction)someButton2 {

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log Out?" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

alertView.tag = TAG_TWO;
[alertView show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView.tag == TAG_ONE) { 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:101-101-1010"]];

} else if (alertView.tag == TAG_TWO){ 
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
}
```

Comment: use buttonIndex to get cancel event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `TAG` for only the `UIAlertview` , but you can Identify the `button` using button `Index`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

if (alertView.tag == TAG_ONE) {
if(alertView.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex){
// Do cancel
}
else{
// Do the success thing
}
}
else if (alertView.tag == TAG_TWO) {
// same thing followed
}
}
```

*buttonIndex == 0 // for OK* , *buttonIndex == 1 // for Cancel*

additional [Reference](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2982-2-button-uialertview-which-button-was-pressed.html)

Comment: are you want to open the alert if user click the cancel button

Answer (score 0):

You must add `if (alertView.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex){
// Do cancel
}`  before asking `if (alertView.tag == TAG_ONE) {`